# How to generate Random numbers, then exclude array of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

i would like to generate random numbers from 1-50, then exclude an array like; 4,7,10,20,35 etc

i tried this;

```js
let mainNum = 50
let exclNum = [4, 7, 10, 20, 35];
if (!exclNum.includes(mainNum)) {
  console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * mainNum) + 1)
}
```

but it still generates numbers that's still in the array,
please is there anything i am missing?

Thanks for your response in advance

Comment: You need to check if exclNum includes your generated random number, right now you're just checking if it includes 50, which it doesn't, so it will always run.

Comment: I removed the jQuery tag since the question had none of that in there

Comment: If the number of excluded numbers is small compared to the number of included numbers, then you can use [_rejection sampling_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). (Just generate random numbers in a loop, and if you generate an excluded number then loop again, otherwise, return the number.) but If not, then it may be more appropriate to construct a new array with the remaining valid possibilities included, and choose from among them. `Array.from(Array(50).keys()).map(x=>x+1).filter(x => !exclNum.includes(x));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the random number first, then check if it's in the array. Do this in a loop until it's not in the array.

```js
let mainNum = 50
let exclNum = [4, 7, 10, 20, 35];
let ranNum;
while (true) {
  ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * mainNum) + 1;
  if (!exclNum.includes(ranNum)) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log(ranNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently checking whether `exclNum` includes `mainNum`, which is 50.

Instead, generate the random number and check whether `exclNum` includes it:

```js
let mainNum = 50
let exclNum = [4, 7, 10, 20, 35];

while(!exclNum.includes((randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * mainNum) + 1))){
  console.log(randomNum)
  break;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A do... while loop is more concise

```js
function myRandom(mainNum, exclude) {
    let r;
    do {
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * mainNum) + 1;
    } while(exclude.includes(r))
    return r;
}

console.log(myRandom(50, [4, 7, 20, 35]));
console.log(myRandom(50, [4, 7, 20, 35]));
console.log(myRandom(50, [4, 7, 20, 35]));
console.log(myRandom(50, [4, 7, 20, 35]));
console.log(myRandom(50, [4, 7, 20, 35]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you two different approaches using [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) to simplify the randomness and make it cryptographically secure.

1. This could execute a ton of times before landing on a number that hasn't been excluded:

```js
var result;
while([4, 7, 10, 20, 35].indexOf(result = rando(1, 50)) > -1);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```

2. This will fill up an array with allowed numbers and pick one of those.

```js
for(var nums = [4, 7, 10, 20, 35], i = 1; i <= 50; i++) nums.indexOf(i) + 1 ? nums.shift() : nums.push(i);
console.log(rando(nums).value);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```

---

If you want the plain javascript version of this stuff, here you go!

1)

```js
var result;
var min = 1;
var max = 50;

while([4, 7, 10, 20, 35].indexOf(result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min) > -1);
console.log(result);
```

2)

```js
var nums = [4, 7, 10, 20, 35];
var min = 1;
var max = 50;

for(var i = min; i <= max; i++) nums.indexOf(i) + 1 ? nums.shift() : nums.push(i);
console.log(nums[Math.floor(Math.random() * nums.length)]);
```

Comment: I reject your claim that it could execute "a ton of times".  The probability of one rejection is 5/50, or 10%.  The probability that this would happen even just 9 times in a row is 0.1^9 or about 1 in a billion.  Furthermore, I don't believe there's enough entropy in a typical JavaScript implementation's pseudo random number generator to permit a sequence of more than about 10 such numbers in a row using `Math.random` due to the choice of algorithm.

Comment: I'm talking about the approach, not the specific numbers we're dealing with here. Imagine we're picking a number from 1-10,000 but 9,998 of those are excluded- and we need to do that 5 times.